# BACI ANOVA with nesting in interaction

Tags: r, anova, interaction, nested-data

I'm doing a BACI (before-after-control-impact) analysis. The data structure is as follows: 2 sites (one control and one impact), 2 years before and 2 years after. Assuming that sampling years aren't the same between the two sites, I want to follow Underwood's 1991 paper ("Beyond BACI: Experimental designs for detecting human environmental impacts on temporal variations in natural populations"). Here's a clip of the relevant bit, where the ANOVA table is set up.

[image]

This is my current model setup:

```
mod <- lm(Value ~ BA + CI + BA*CI + (BA*CI)/YearFac, data = sub)
```

However, when I run `car:::Anova(mod)`, this is the table I get:

```
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Value
              Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
BA            439.98  1 49.4264 5.330e-10 ***
CI             71.36  1  8.0159 0.0058159 ** 
BA:CI         139.23  1 15.6412 0.0001605 ***
BA:CI:YearFac 322.36  3 12.0710 1.237e-06 ***
Residuals     738.84 83
```

A couple of questions:

1. Is my model specification correct?
2. Why is the Df for `BA:CI:YearFac` 3? Based on the Underwood paper, it should be `4*(t-1)`, and with `t=2`, that means `Df = 4`.
3. In Underwood's table, what does the "F ratio versus" column mean? Does it mean that I would be taking the sum of squares for `BA:CI` and testing it against the SS of `BA:CI:YearFac`? Does the rest of the Anova table get ignored then??